# getData doesn't work, returns empty

Tags: magento

I create my custom attribute, but when I go show this with my method it doesn't work!

See was do... create my attribute..

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$config = array(
    'position' => 1,
    'required'=> 0,
    'label' => 'Height',
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'text',
    'apply_to' => 'simple,bundle,grouped,configurable'
);

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'height' , $config);
```

and I get a list of items in checkout...

```
$items = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($items as $item){

    echo $item->getSku() .'<br/>'; //just test... and all right!

    echo $item->getHeight() .'<br/>'; //return empty! or....
    echo $item->getData('height') .'<br/>';//return empty!
}
```

I set values in this attribute's fiels in my backend.

Thanks for help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attributes probably aren't being loaded by default.  A cheat, without fixing the root problem of adding `height` to the collection's `addAttributeToSelect()` statement would be to load the product model again:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
echo $product->getHeight();
```

This doesn't solve the root of the problem though, and fires off an additional database query.

I asked a similar question a couple of months ago regarding loading additional data which contains some more information, although more related to collection loading than individual models: [Retrieving additional data from already loaded Magento models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483877/retrieving-additional-data-from-already-loaded-magento-models).

Comment: Your cheat fixed my problem too, so I assume it has the same cause. That said, what does, "your attributes probably aren't being loaded by default" mean?? How do I load my attributes by default?

Answer (score 0):

Try echo $item->getProduct()->getHeight();

Comment: echo $item->getProduct()->getSku() .'<br/>'; //ok!

Comment: echo $item->getProduct()->getData('sku') .'<br/>'; //ok!

Comment: echo $item->getProduct()->getHeight() .'<br/>'; //return empty again

Comment: echo $item->getProduct()->getData('height') .'<br/>'; //return empty again

Comment: After I don't know this way to have attribute. The only thing I can tell is the $items you get from Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() are comming from sale_quote_item and not catalog_product. To access to the attribute you need to use $item->getProduct(). I hope someone else can help you a bit more. Good luck