# adding products compare to magento using products attributes (category)

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

Hy ,, Im trying to make Magento compare products by grouping all products with the same cateogry and compare them together ,and group the other and compare them together..etc instead of comparing all them togher, I have tried this code

```
      collection.php

      class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection extends   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract

      public function addCategoryFilterH($request)
      {

        $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_id'] =$request;
        unset($this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor']);


        $this->_applyZeroStoreProductLimitations();

        $this->_applyProductLimitations();

            return $this;


}
```

then i do in products compare this :

```
          list.phtml
          $this_original=$this;
          $cat15=$this->getItems()->addCategoryFilterH(15);
           ...for loop throw this products ....
          $this=$this_original;
          $cat8=$this->getItems()->addCategoryFilterH(8);
          ...for loop throw this products ....
          ...next category id ... 
          ...for loop ... etc
```

but my code did not work , any Help?

Comment: Do you have some page, with multiple categories or what? Or you display category with multiple child categories?

Comment: i just want to override product compare default functionality, so it can show compare products by their category

Comment: What does it mean now working. Please be more specifi? Did you checked logs?

Comment: yes ,, it give me the same output .. filter only work for the first time ..

Comment: Do *not* ask the same question twice, if anything, edit the *original* version of your question to reflect new/updated information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in collection.php add this function , you don't need to write class name as i did , i wrote it ensure that you are modifying the correct file

```
  class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection extends   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract

  public function addCategoryFilterH($request)
  {

    $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_id'] =$request;
    unset($this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor']);


    $this->_applyZeroStoreProductLimitations();

    $this->_applyProductLimitations();

        return $this;
```

in list.php "app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"
add this code at the top of you file

```
<?php
$thiscount=clone $this;
$this1=clone $this;
$comparecats=array();
?>
 <?php foreach($thiscount->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php


$att=$_item->getCategoryIds();
array_push($comparecats,$att[0]);

 ?>
  <?php endforeach;

echo "<br>";

 ?>

<?php

$comparecats = array_unique($comparecats);

$this2= clone $this;

?>

<?php foreach ($comparecats  as $cateid):
unset($this);
$this2=clone $this1;
$this2->getItems()->addCategoryFilterByCategoryId($cateid);
echo "<br>";
?>
.........for loop your products using this ...............
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yes ,, it give me the same output .. filter only work for the first time ..
```

Try to reload collections. Similar problem might be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355370/magento-ordering-collections-after-adding-items/8355654#8355654)

```
$collection->clear();
$collection->....//here you add some logic for filtering;
$collection->load();//here collection with new filters will be loaded.
```

**UPDATE 1**

So my advice is to create another method in your block which resets collection. Or even add reset to your category loading function. Well it is up to you.

Comment: Specifically, `$this_original=$this` does not create a backup copy of `$this`, it only creates a second reference to it.

Comment: $this is not a collection. $this is a block. You shouldn't make a copy of block in your phtml. Better have another method which resets collection.

Answer (score 0):

I have only one idea. Import product via Store Manager for Magento into csv and then compare them. I'm not sure that your code is quite good for this action.

Comment: product compare is for users who use my website ,,, not for system administrator

Answer (score 0):

in collection.php add this function , you don't need to write class name as i did , i wrote it ensure that you are modifying the correct file

```
  class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection extends   Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract

  public function addCategoryFilterH($request)
  {

    $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_id'] =$request;
    unset($this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor']);


    $this->_applyZeroStoreProductLimitations();

    $this->_applyProductLimitations();

        return $this;
```

in list.php "app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"
add this code at the top of you file

```
<?php
$thiscount=clone $this;
$this1=clone $this;
$comparecats=array();
?>
 <?php foreach($thiscount->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php


$att=$_item->getCategoryIds();
array_push($comparecats,$att[0]);

 ?>
  <?php endforeach;

echo "<br>";

 ?>

<?php

$comparecats = array_unique($comparecats);

$this2= clone $this;

?>

<?php foreach ($comparecats  as $cateid):
unset($this);
$this2=clone $this1;
$this2->getItems()->addCategoryFilterByCategoryId($cateid);
echo "<br>";
?>
.........for loop your products using this ...............
```