# Magento: Sorting a product collection

Tags: php, sorting, magento

I'm creating a template to display featured products on the home page, and I'd like to control the order of the products.

This is what I'm using at the moment to fetch a product collection based on a category:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
?>
```

No specific sorting at all.

When I were going to sort the products, I expected this to work:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
?>
```

But there's no difference at all. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento - load only configurable products](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280392/magento-load-only-configurable-products)

Comment: No dublicate; that question is about performance, this question is about sorting.

Comment: I shouldn't have used the default "duplicate" message, it was misleading. I meant to show that `getLoadedProductCollection` gets a collection that is already loaded and needs to be reset before you can adjust the sort order (or filter).

Comment: Feels like a dirty solution, but it works - thank you for the tip!

Comment: I guess loaded product collection means that collection is already loaded (query to db was already run) at this point. That's why you can't reorder already loaded collection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this one I have worked on the same way try it.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
             ->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSort('name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

for descending order:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSort('name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC);
```

for product with its category:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
             ->getProductCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSort('name', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

Or you can find more help on [magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento).

Comment: you can use wherever you want I mean when you are dealing with any of the above situation.]