# Magento Product Listing - Sort by product type(Configurable then Simple)

Tags: php, magento

In /app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml you have the following snippet that loops through and displays the **$_productCollection** contents.

```
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I'd like to know is how to have the $_productCollection sorted by product type.
Ultimately what I want is to have configurable products show first, then simple products.

Help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things that makes product collections in category views such a pain to customize is the coupling between toolbar, layered navigation, actual list display, and even with the `Mage_Review` module, which *explicitly loads the collection in an event observer!*

At first it seems that you could use the typical collection utilities (e.g. `addAttributeToSort()`) to add your conditions, but you will find that this will not work at the template level, as *the collection data is already loaded*. I surmise that the collection getter method being named `getLoadedProductCollection()` is a hint from the core team.

The lazy-load implementation of Magento collections is such that once they have been `load()`ed (directly or indirectly), they will not reload (i.e. transact with the database) without explicitly being forced to do so.

So, you need to set your ordering parameters on the collection before it is loaded. Tracing through the `getLoadedProductCollection()` method gets one quickly to the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection()` method, which is where the block determines if it is on a product page (by checking the registry, yuck) or not. Tracking the state of the collection through the call stack, it can be determined that it's not loaded until the block's `_beforeToHtml()` method. If you were to trace back from the output, you can see that the collection is explicitly loaded by the Mage_Review observer, which consumes the `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event (see `Mage_Review_Model_Observer::catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml()`). That gives a starting point and endpoint.

I should hopefully have a solution later.

Comment: Hey @benmarks, I really appreciate it. I'd deducted that problem of the collection already being loaded from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280392/magento-load-only-configurable-products. But it presents problems relate to the clone method as per the comments.

Comment: I seem to have finally succeeded. I haven't finished testing in depth but I've essentially replacex the first line in list.phtml: `$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()` with `$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()->clear()->addAttributeToSort( 'type_id', 'ASC' )->load();`. This seems to keep my layered navigation but sort by configurable then simple.

Comment: You will need to do some testing with the toolbar's sorting and paging, and with the reviews as well. I suspect that both of these will be out of whack.

Comment: So far so good. Paging works. Sorting and Reviews are disabled anyways. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, only issue I could foresee if you ever add bundles, those will show before configurables.