# Product selection Magento

Tags: magento

im trying to show a list of products and i whant to filter so the 2 first products in my collection dosent show and control how meny products that will be loaded .
The product are filterd by our_reviews and sorted by reviewdate.
I want the first and second of the result to not show and start showing product 3 and so on.

This is what i have so far

```
    $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
         ->addAttributeToFilter('our_reviews', array('neq' => ''))
         ->setOrder('reviewdate','DESC')
         ->setPage(1,10)
         ->load();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following thread walks through how to limit the number of products returned in a product collection:

[magento limiting number of returned items in product collection call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854110/magento-limiting-number-of-returned-items-in-product-collection-call)

If you want to skip the first two products, that's easiest to do in your loop. Something like this would work:

```
<?php $skiptwo = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
      <?php if ($skiptwo < 2):
             <?php $skiptwo++;  ?>
      <?php else: ?>
              <?php echo $_product->getName() //do all the stuff you want here
      <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```